# Query Timeout spring xml Parameter

Tags: java, spring

I got this bean in my data-access-functions-config.xml:

```
<bean id="pbfuLinkTrasmissionDao" class="******.zja.dao.stored.StoredDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="easyDataSource" />
    <property name="parameterHandlerManager" ref="parameterHandlerManager" />
    <property name="queryTimeout" value="${store.procedure.timeout}" />
    <property name="storedDaoConfiguration">
        <bean class="******.zja.dao.stored.config.StoredDaoConfiguration">
            <property name="spSchema" value="DSVIL" />
            <property name="spPackage" value="WAPK_EASY_SERVICE" />
            <property name="spName" value="wapr_PolicyCustomerLinkage " />
            <property name="storedType" value="PROCEDURE" />
            <property name="spParameters">
                <list>
```

My .property file got:

```
store.procedure.timeout=1
```

I have problems with this property

```
<property name="queryTimeout" value="${store.procedure.timeout}" />
```

The procedure runs for about 5 seconds, but it does not give any timeout.
Am I missing something for this configuration?

The procedure runs well, also the call. I have only to add this `queryTimeout`. Is right to use this in this way? Do I have to add some others parameters or java parameters?

it does not go in timeout even if i do this:

```
<property name="queryTimeout" value="1" />
```

Comment: Please add more details - environment, database, who implements the database calls (like hibernate), other frameworks, etc.

Comment: the procedure runs well and call also, i have only to add this timeout, i'm using  oracle DB with wsdl/xsd calls.
i mean: is possible use this property? it's correct? or i have to add other java parameters? or something